# matplotlib x axe longer than dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to matplotlib and can't find a way to "reduce" the x axe. I have tried to search for an answer with the search bar but I might not have the right vocabulary, so sorry if it has already been answered (and I believe it is as it seems pretty basic)

[Here is my graph with an x axes longer than my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkp7B.png)

I would love to be able to stop the ticks at 52 instead of 60 as my dataset doesn't go beyond this points

Here is my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.xlabel('Semaines')
plt.ylabel('Visites')
plt.plot(visite_web_2016.semaine,visite_web_2016.Web_Visites)
plt.plot(visite_web_2017.semaine,visite_web_2017.Web_Visites)
plt.title('Visites Web')
plt.legend(['visite web 2016','visite web 2017'], loc=0)
#plt.xticks([10,20,30,40,50], ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"])
#plt.ticks = np.arange(0,9,1)
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

I have tried to use xticks and ticks without success (in my example they are here just to show where I have been using them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit the x-axis to a specific value. You could do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.xlabel('Semaines')
plt.ylabel('Visites')
plt.plot(visite_web_2016.semaine,visite_web_2016.Web_Visites)
plt.plot(visite_web_2017.semaine,visite_web_2017.Web_Visites)
plt.title('Visites Web')
plt.legend(['visite web 2016','visite web 2017'], loc=0)

plt.xlim(xmin, xmax) # xmin and xmax are min and max value of x-axis.

#plt.xticks([10,20,30,40,50], ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50"])
#plt.ticks = np.arange(0,9,1)
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

In your case you could have `min` and `max` values set to:

```
plt.xlim(0, 52)
```